# What is the difference between kobject, device_create and my code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently reading a book entitled ["Linux device drivers" from O'Reilly](http://www2.electron.frba.utn.edu.ar/~gjoyuela/archivos/linux/ldd3.pdf).

Thing is that this book imo isn't really a guide on *how* to write drivers but it instead explains all the apis and their prinicples.
So I tried writing a small driver -which doesn't do anything interesting -with what I read so far.
Thing is:

- I don't know which file I can execute `cat` on or `echo` to in order to invoke my callback functions
- it looks nothing like all the other code snippets I found online

The different pieces of code:

- my code (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8tVyTJTPBQ/)
  creates:

  `$ls /sys/module/main/`
   `oresize  holders  initsize  initstate  notes  refcnt  sections  srcversion  taint  uevent`

  `no new entry in /dev`
- code snippet using device_create:   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cJxjdyXjhX/ [source](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/) 
   creates:

  `$ ls /sys/module/main/`
   `coresize  holders  initsize  initstate  notes  refcnt  sections  srcversion  taint  uevent`

  `$ ls -l /dev/ebbchar`
  `crw------- 1 root root 238, 0 Mai 28 07:52 /dev/ebbchar`
- code using kobjects: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nt3XvZs7vF/ [source](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/sysfs-in-linux-kernel/)
  creates:

  `$ls -l /sys/kernel/`
    `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Dec 17 16:29 etx_sysfs`

I can see that my code successfully created a bunch of files under /sys/kernel. Now what is the difference in endgoal between my code and the two other snippets? Should I use device_create/kobjects or maybe none of those? The book I am reading doesn't mention anywhere the functions used by the 2 other pieces of code. So not sure which way I am supposed to follow...

Thanks_xe

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use newest available API for your kernel version. LDDv3 doesn't know anything about udev mechanism.

Comment: @0andriy How do you know this is not the newest API? How do you stay up to date with the newest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`device_create()` creates a device and registers it with sysfs, and create necessary kobjects.

To create necessary kobjects, kobject-related functions(`kobject_init()`, `kobject_add()`, ...) are called in `device_create()`.

If you need to create a device, you should call one of device creation functions like `device_create()`.

Comment: How do you stay up to date with the newest API? Because the book I am reading doesn't speak even once about kobjects...

Comment: @traducerad To check the newest API, please refer to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/. If you want to check APIs of a specific version of kernel, refer to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question of how to keep up with latest api- Most api if renamed or updated retain similar name and reside mostly in the same header file so a quick grep on the source or easier is http://elixir.bootlin.com/ and search the source doc for a particular function in the Linux release you are working on. if you cant find the API in that release then go through the header to find the new API as the name will almost be the same for example when you will read the Timer chapter , you will find that setup_timer() has been changed to timer_setup(). and few other changes here and there.
If you feel like you can keep up with the latest discussion by subscribing to the kernel maillist or reading the documentation.